# Need to lock an axis of the soft body animation

Tags: animation, soft-body, axis

I have to make an animation of a bouncy sofbody, but it keeps moving around.

I thought I could lock the Z axis for the softbody's animation, but I could not find information about it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Add an object constraint, limit location to the body and limit the distances.(you might want to start at a negative z).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Soft body is a **deformation** not a transformation.  Take a look at the orange dot indicating the object's center during a soft body sim: it never moves.  (Or rotates, or scales.)  Instead, the SB-deformed vertices move around inside the existing object transformation.  That means that locking axes, or using object constraints, won't do anything.

If you need to control the position of a soft body, while still letting physics do its thing, you do so by using soft body **goal** settings.  Goal exerts forces between the current soft body deformation and its pre-SB position.  Here, the soft body is exerting a strength 0.4 force toward the positions indicated by the wireframe:

[image]

You can assign specific vertices to goal groups.  When you do so, the goal strength of vertices fully assigned to that group will be default * max, and the goal strength of verts not assigned to that group will be default * min, and verts partially weighted will fall between those two values:

[image]

The assigned vert stays where it is, because its goal strength is 1.0, full strength.  The other verts move around with goal strength 0.4, and of course all of the vertices exert forces on each other via their edges.

Not all of your soft body vertices have to be *visible* vertices.  It is often useful to create goal vertices that are connected to other vertices via edges only, which then transmit forces from your goal-marked vertices:

[image]

Here, only a single vertex is assigned to goal, and the other vertices hang from it. That single vertex is never intended to be part of any kind of render.  It exists only to allow us to control the simulation.  It's a little like controlling a marionette.

We can use those kind of "strings" to control how our soft body behaves in other ways.  If we draw strings in the z axis, and assign their ends to goal:

[image]

we can create a soft body that finds it much easier to move in its X or Y axis than in its Z axis, because movement in the Z axis requires more stretching (or pulling) than movement in the X or Y axes does.